# systemd errors when two devices share the same mount point

Tags: systemd, fstab

I just updated and installed a whole load of debian packages and now I am getting errors due to my particular fstab file config. I have 2 drives which I never mount simultaneously and which both have the same mount point (`/etc/fstab` snippet):

```
UUID=xxxx-xxxx /media/strontium vfat user,rw,exec,nofail 0 2                    
UUID=yyyy-yyyy /media/strontium vfat user,rw,exec,nofail 0 2
```

However, after the installations, systemd is complaining about this:

```
[518052.191024] systemd-fstab-generator[28811]: Failed to create mount unit file /run/systemd/generator/media-strontium.mount, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?
```

I actually don't want to use systemd to mount drives for me at all. I previously used `sudo mount -a` and this just went through my `/etc/fstab` file and mounted anything that was plugged in.

Is it possible to turn off the systemd mounting functionality so that I can mount my own drives manually as before?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know anyway round this systemd restriction, as the mount point directory name is converted into a systemd filename. The simplest answer may be to remove the entries from the fstab and write a tiny script to do the mounts on demand:

```
#!/bin/bash
( mount -U xxxx-xxxx /media/strontium -t vfat -o rw,exec ||
  mount -U yyyy-yyyy /media/strontium -t vfat -o rw,exec
) && echo ok
```

Don't forget, after modifying `/etc/fstab`, to do a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` to ensure systemd notices your changes.

---

If you want to keep the entries in `/etc/fstab` you could use make the second mount point a symbolic link to the first, eg `ln -s /media/strontium /media/strontium2`. When the mount is done the link is followed so it ends up on the directory as usual. You must add option `noauto` to both lines in this case, else systemd will get confused and immediately unmount what it thinks is the first entry.

Instead of a symbolic link you can instead use a real directory and then do a manual *bind mount* to mount that directory at the wanted place:

```
mount --bind /media/strontium2 /media/strontium
```

You must remember to umount this bind mount as well as the first mount.

---

In the past you could have added a udev rule to call mount explicitly when you see the UUID appear, eg in `/etc/udev/rules.d/92-my.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="xxxx-xxxx", RUN+="/usr/bin/mount /dev/%k /media/strontium"
```

but this doesn't work with recent systemd's, as it runs `udevd` in a
separate mount namespace, so although it does the mount, you cannot see it.
I don't yet know the reason for this namespace, but you can in principle
override this feature by creating a file
`/etc/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service` with the 2 lines

```
.include /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service
MountFlags=shared
```

---

If you want something that is still automatic, then an alternative is to monitor the events from `udevd` concerning block devices and do an explicit mount. For example, run permanently:

```
#!/bin/bash
# udevadm monitor outputs a stanza ending with a blank line
#  UDEV  [5291328.3] add  /devices/pci0000:00/.../usb3/..../block/sdd (block)
#  ACTION=add
#  DEVNAME=/dev/sdd
stdbuf -o L udevadm monitor -u -p -s 'block/disk' |
awk -F= '
$0~/^ACTION=/{ action = $2 }
$0~/^DEVNAME=/{ name = $2 }
$0~/^ID_FS_UUID=/{ uuid = $2 }
$0~/^$/{ if(action=="add" && (uuid=="xxxx-xxxx"||uuid=="yyyy-yyyy")
          system("sudo mount mount " name " /media/strontium -t vfat -o rw,exec")
         uuid=""
       }'
```

Comment: thanks for all the ideas! i won't mark as the correct answer just in case someone knows how to disable systemd's auto mount functionality and writes an answer for this.