# creating an overlay directly over a mount (systemd-fstab-generator causes error)

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, fstab, overlayfs

I would like to create an overlay over my /var directory.  I am using debian/stretch with a recent kernel and install. systemd 232.  I am using something along the lines of (all lines with an implied sudo):

```
mkdir /srv/overlay
dd if=/dev/zero of=/srv/overlay/.var.img bs=4096 count=204800
mkfs -t ext4 -L ofsvar /srv/overlay/.var.img
mkdir /mnt/.var.ofs
mount /srv/overlay/.var.img /mnt/.var.ofs/
mkdir /mnt/.var.ofs/.workdir
mkdir /mnt/.var.ofs/.upper
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/var,upperdir=/mnt/.var.ofs/.upper,workdir=/mnt/.var.ofs/.workdir /var
sed -i -e "\$aoverlay /var overlay noauto,x-systemd.automount,lowerdir=/var,upperdir=/mnt/.var.ofs/.upper,workdir=/mnt/.var.ofs/.workdir 0 0" /etc/fstab
```

The mount statement confirms that the concept works.  The sed statement updates /etc/fstab with something that should work upon reboot.

But because that /var statement in /etc/fstab conflicts with the already existing /var statement in /etc/fstab (I have a separate partition assigned to /var), systemd's systemd-fstab-generator indicates that it is a duplicate and will not create an appropriate entry in the run/systemd/generator directory structure.  I am not even sure if it is possible to manually create a set of files in that directory to make it work.

Any thoughts on if this is possible?   Or how to do it?

Comment: Is relocating your original `/var` out of question?

Comment: Well, I think it is more of a generic problem which might have a solution.  I would like to apply this to root (/).  So that problem can't go away with a relocation ;-)  /var was only an example.

Comment: Right. Meanwhile, you may want to check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318080/systemd-errors-when-two-devices-share-the-same-mount-point for other workarounds.